# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest . MAVEN; TestNG, Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

Hi I'm trying to run Selenium script with Maven, TestNG in Eclipse. 
First I right click on my project and select TestNG | Convert to TestNG(testing.xml is created). Then I go to the Run Configurations and create a new launch TestNGl and click Run. When run it I got this error:

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.11.0
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at test.java.NewTest.beforeTest(NewTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest afterTest
SKIPPED: f
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at test.java.NewTest.beforeTest(NewTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1

## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

I have the following code:

```
package test.java;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class NewTest {

private WebDriver driver;

@Test   

public void f() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String exePath = "/Users/********/Downloads/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);

    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.apple.com/");  
    String title = driver.getTitle();                
    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Apple"));         
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {  
    driver = new ChromeDriver();  
}       
@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    driver.quit();          
}       

}
```

And following pom.xml:

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
<artifactId>TestMaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set property in @beforeTest method bec. it will run before @Test.

In your case you are trying to create driver instance before setting it property.

Try below code :-

```
  @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {  
       String exePath = "/Users/********/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();  
    }
```

---

```
package test.java;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class NewTest {

private WebDriver driver;

@Test   

public void f() {

    driver.get("https://www.apple.com/");  
    String title = driver.getTitle();                
    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Apple"));         
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {  
String exePath = "/Users/********/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);

    driver = new ChromeDriver();  
}       
@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    driver.quit();          
}       

}
```

Comment: I try it, but got the same error: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

Comment: String exePath = "/Users/********/Downloads/chromedriver" Ur path should be till chromedriver.exe.. refer syntx                                                                           
      String exePath = "/Users/********/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe";

Comment: chromedriver is not *.exe file. It says 'Unix executable'

Comment: I assume, you are using Mac OS. You don't have to specify the extension for your Chromedriver executable. Modify your exePath as exePath = "/Users/********/Downloads/chromedriver" in beforeTest method.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me when i removed `.exe` extension from the path. For example:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/***/***/chromedriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `failed CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:openqa selenium`. After switched my project to STS, it worked fine(problem with my eclipse, I think). Download STS here https://download.springsource.com/release/STS4/4.17.0.RELEASE/dist/e4.26/spring-tool-suite-4-4.17.0.RELEASE-e4.26.0-win32.win32.x86_64.zip

Comment: Please don't link external resources and describe the solution instead

Comment: I found this sts file after a long search (here https://spring.io/blog/category/releases).  I thought it'd be helpful for newbies.